# How to swap byte nibbles?

Tags: c++, bit

Given these bytes (hexadecimal representation):

```
0F  
1A  
2C
```

how can I get:

```
F0  
A1  
C2
```

?

Comment: Those "tetrads" are called "nibbles."

Comment: It is a dupe, and it's unfortunate that the original has a wrong accepted answer.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: didn't know this, sorry. I'll fix title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bitwise operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm).

```
((x & 0x0f) << 4) | ((x & 0xf0) >> 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
((x & 0x0f) << 4 ) | ((( x & 0xf0) >> 4) & 0xf )
```

This looks a lot like Josh Kelley's answer, but Josh's answer is wrong.  Here's why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  signed char x = 0x80;
  x >>= 4;
  printf( "%x\n", x ); 
}
```

Gives output:

```
0xfffffff8
```

Because the `>>` operator preserves the sign bit of the shifted operand.  I.e., a 1 in the most significant bit will be propagated leftward to preserve the sign of the value.

Comment: Are you sure? My answer worked when I tested it. `(x & 0xf0)` should cause `x` to get promoted to `int` or `unsigned`, so its MSB will be 0, so it won't get sign-extended, right?

Comment: The sign extension in your example is actually being done at the `printf` call. `signed char x = 0x80; printf("%x\n", x);` gives `ffffff80`.

Comment: So, for `unsigned char` your answer and Josh's answer are equal?