# C - Copying nibbles from one byte to another to generate a bitshift by 4

Tags: c

While I know how to copy one bit from one byte to another (as explained here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193800/c-bit-operations-copy-one-bit-from-one-byte-to-another-byte)), I have a problem for a full 4 bit shift from one byte to another byte from a different array (especially for up to 106 bytes).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998810/how-to-swap-byte-nibbles), how to shift two nibbles at once (for a single byte) and I also tried to implement it:

```
  char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  char gen_message[strlen(input) + 1];
  for(int loop = (strlen(input) - 1); loop >= 0; loop--)
  {
    ((gen_message[(loop + 1)]) & 0xF0) = ((*input[loop]) & 0x0F);
    ((gen_message[loop]) & 0x0F) = ((*input[loop]) & 0xF0);
  }
  gen_message[0] & 0xF0 = 0x4;
```

Note: Input can between 1 and up to 106 symbols, hence the malloc.

However, I get an error (invalid type of argument of unary '*') and even then I'm not sure if it would be correct.

Can anybody point to a solution or can explain where my brainfart lies, so that I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

-Greetings

Comment: `input` is a pointer, but `input[loop]` is a char.  Just get rid of the `*`

Comment: on the second line `strlen(input)` but the string pointed by _input_ is not initialized

Comment: `gen_message[0] & 0xF0 = 0x4;` gives a compiler error: *left operand must be l-value* and on other lines too.

Comment: What do you expect `strlen(input)` to be the measure of? You don't write anything to `input` after allocating it, so it's not a string, and nothing about how you use it suggests that you even mean it to be a string. Then you proceed to try to dereference its (still uninitialized) elements (`char`s) as though they were pointers? Did you omit some code that actually puts the input in `input`?

Comment: @WeatherVane same for `((gen_message[(loop + 1)]) & 0xF0) =` and `((gen_message[loop]) & 0x0F)`

Comment: @bruno just noticed anyway thanks.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong with every single line here (well, except the ones that contain only `{` or `}`), so it's really hard to tell what this is even intended to do.

Comment: if input can be up to 106 symbols why is it just using `malloc(sizeof(int))` and not the actual number of expected symbols?  Then you wouldn't attempt to perform `strlen(input)` (which as pointed out returns a garbage length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally (ignoring bitfields) C can't store anything smaller than a `char`. To work around that you can read the whole `char`, modify a portion of it, then store the whole (modified) `char`.

Note that in C `char` may be signed (e.g. maybe a signed octet with range -128 to +127); and this makes it messy to modify due to uncertainty (e.g. behaviour of "right shift of signed integer" isn't defined). For that reason I'd strongly recommend using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

To write the lowest nibble you'd want to do something like:

```
    dest = dest & 0xF0;        // Clear all bits in the low nibble
    dest = dest | new_nibble;  // Set new bits in the low nibble
```

To write the highest nibble you'd want to do something like:

```
    dest = dest & 0x0F;               // Clear all bits in the high nibble
    dest = dest | (new_nibble << 4);  // Set new bits in the high nibble
```

To read nibbles you'd do something like:

```
    low_nibble = src & 0x0F;
    high_nibble = (src & 0xF0) >> 4;
```

Copying is just reading and then writing. For example, to copy the lowest nibble from `src` to the highest nibble in `dest` you could:

```
    nibble = src & 0x0F;
    dest = dest & 0x0F;             // Clear all bits in the high nibble
    dest = dest | (nibble << 4);    // Set new bits in the high nibble
```

With elements of arrays it might look like this:

```
    nibble1 = input[loop] & 0x0F;
    nibble2 = (input[loop] & 0xF0) >> 4;
    gen_message[loop + 1] = gen_message[loop + 1] & 0xF0;
    gen_message[loop + 1] = gen_message[loop + 1] | nibble1;
    gen_message[loop] = gen_message[loop] & 0x0F;
    gen_message[loop] = gen_message[loop] | (nibble2 << 4);
```

This can also be done more concisely:

```
    gen_message[loop + 1] &= 0xF0;
    gen_message[loop + 1] |= input[loop] & 0x0F;
    gen_message[loop] &= 0x0F;
    gen_message[loop] |= ((input[loop] & 0xF0) >> 4) << 4;
```

Of course if know that the destination contains zeros already (e.g. due to `memset()` or `calloc()`), you can skip the "clear nibble" parts:

```
    gen_message[loop + 1] |= input[loop] & 0x0F;
    gen_message[loop] |= ((input[loop] & 0xF0) >> 4) << 4;
```

**EDIT**

The other commentors are right - due to the number of problems it's hard to guess what you're actually trying to do. I think that you might (but might not) be trying to do something like this:

```
unsigned char *shiftArray4Bits( unsigned char *srcArray ) {
    int srcLen = strlen(srcArray);
    unsigned char temp = 0;
    unsigned char *destArray;

    destArray = malloc(srcLen + 1);
    if(destArray == NULL) {
        return NULL;     // Failed to allocate memory
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < srcLen; i++) {
        dest[i] = temp | ((srcArray[i] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        temp = (srcArray[i] & 0x0F) << 4;
    }
    dest[i] = temp;
    return dest;
}
```